# MailItem Attachments - Check if File Already Attached

Tags: c#, attachment, outlook-addin, mailitem

I know how to add files to MailItem.Attachments but how do I check if the file is already added to Attachments?

For example, I have file name `"C:\\myFolder\\myFile.txt"`.  How do I check if this file is already attached or not?  I need this to prevent double attaching a file to new email.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var mItem = Outlook.Interfaces.HostAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as MailItem;

if (mItem != null)
{
    //this works fine but I need to check if already attached first like below
    //mItem.Attachments.Add(localFilePath); 

    bool found = false;
    string attachments = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= mItem.Attachments.Count; i++)
    {
        attachments += 
            "DisplayName: " + mItem.Attachments[i].DisplayName //shows just myFile.txt, no path
            + " / FileName: " + mItem.Attachments[i].FileName  //shows just myFile.txt, no path
            + " / PathName: " + mItem.Attachments[i].PathName; //shows ""

        //I tried here PathName, FileName, DisplayName but all return just name, without the path
        if (mItem.Attachments[i].PathName == localFilePath)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        mItem.Attachments.Add(localFilePath); //attach only if not already attached
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is pretty much the best you can do - `FileName` will match, `PathName` will always be empty, and `DisplayName` will be the same as `FileName`.

You can also compare the old and existing file sizes, but do not use `Attachment.Size` as it includes the size of the MAPI specified properties plus the actual file data.

Also don't forget to check that `Attachmeent.Type == olByValue`: you only want regular attachments.

You can also (if the file name matches) save the existing attachment to a temp folder (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`) and compare file sizes. If they match, you can also compare the context (e.g. calculate a CRC).

Note that you cannot access attachment data directly using OOM alone, you'd need Extended MAPI (`IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, IID_IStream, ...)`) or Redemption (I am its author - `Attachment.AsText/AsArray`/etc.). Otherwise you will need to use `Attachment.SaveAsFile` and then delete the temporary file.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  Isn't there a way to check just the path+file name to the path+filename of file I am attaching?  I add a file to Attachments providing file's path+fileName.  I am supprised I cannot get the same from already attached files.

Comment: Nope, the path information is never even stored unless it is a by-reference attachment. On the MAPI level, files do not even come into play - the data comes as IStream into the PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property.

Comment: Thanks a million Dmitry

Comment: I suggest you reconsider the "for (int i = 1; i <= mItem.Attachments.Count; i++)" line, as attachments start at 0, not 1. But ideally I would use "foreach (Attachment att in mail.Attachments)" which at least guarantees you will either have at least one attachment or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and tried to use the `mail.Attachment.Contains()` method, but this always returned `true`. Not sure why.

So I did the following based of my comment above to `Dmit's` answer.

This will check if the file attachment exists, by **name** only. Of course you will need to check for filesize, CRC etc as above to be sure it's 100% the same file.

```
                    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(lFile);

                    if (errLine.Split(":")[0] == fInfo.Name)
                    {
                        Attachment logfile = new Attachment(lFile);
                        bool attachmentFound = false;
                        foreach (Attachment att in mail.Attachments)
                        {
                            if (att.Name == logfile.Name)
                            {
                                attachmentFound = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!attachmentFound)
                            mail.Attachments.Add(logfile);
                    }
```

Comment: `Attachments` collection in OOM does NOT expose a method called `Contains`. Most likely that was an extension method for IEnumerable.

Comment: So could you please edit your answer to suggest an alternative solution using Contains()?

Comment: Using Contains? There is nothing special about it - Contains just loops through the collection comparing each item with a value. How that comparison happens depends on the value on and how the collection elements are cast. And explicit loop like the one you have above are better.